# Three questions about Vim

Tags: windows, file, vim, command-line, directory

I am new to the so-called “best text editor” Vim, and I’m struggling to become familiar with the operations it can perform. Some of the problems I encounter are really odd; I’m hoping that someone can give me some help with these:

1. When I enter gVim and type `:cd.`, the prompt shows that I am in `C:\Windows\System32`. Why is this? I installed Vim in `E:\Vim`. Is it possible to change this default directory to something else?
2. Is there any method to specify a directory in Vim and create a file (using Vim, of course — not in the command line window by running something like `vim someName.txt`) in the specified directory? When I’ve tried commands like `:e someFileName.txt`, I receive error warnings about some swap file. Also, if I search for this `someFileName.txt`, the location is really strange — it is under `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp`. Why?
3. This is even more bizarre: In Windows, the default command line directory is `C:\Users\MyUserName`. I don’t like that, so I’ve changed it to `C:\`. However, if I press the Start button, type `cmd.exe`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the command line window still shows that I am in `C:\Users\MyUserName`. If I click the shortcut icon in the task bar, the directory is correct (`C:\`). Moreover, if I make such a change, and run Vim in the command line, every time that I close a file I receive an error warning:

   ```
   can't write viminfo file C:\_viminfo!
   ```

After some investigation, I’ve found that if I change the command line directory back to `C:\Users\MyUserName`, everything is just fine, and a file named `viminfo` is created under this directory. So why does it do this? Can’t Vim create this `viminfo` file under `C:\`, just as it does in `C:\Users\MyUserName`?

Comment: Have you got a local _vimrc file? Do you see the same behaviour if you run vim without any customisations: `gvim -u NONE`?

Comment: @PrinceGoulash yes I have a _vimrc file under `E:\VIM`, and I did not install any additional plug-ins. The behavior is the same if I run `gvim -u NONE`. One small question here: every time I edit the _vimrc file, there is another file named _vimrc~ created in the same directory, what is this file?

Answer (score 5):

1. This is the default on Windows. I seem to remember that it depends on how it was installed. Anyway, you can change it to whatever you want by typing the following from *normal* mode:

   ```
   :cd <your path>
   ```

   If you want it to be persistent across sessions, create `$HOME/_vimrc` (if you don't have it already) and add the line above without the colon.
2. You get that error message about swapfiles because you are working in a protected directory: the swap can't be created. The answer above should solve this problem in a general way. Anyway, you can edit files anywhere you can write to disk. In the example below, `~` is a shortcut to your `$HOME` directory, like in UNIX:

   ```
   :e ~\filename
   ```
3. Do you have write rights in `C:`? I'm not a Windows user so don't take my word for it, but I think that `C:\Users\MyUserName` should *really* be your `$HOME`.
4. Did you run `vimtutor`? It's the absolute best way to learn the basic editing commands.

   ***edit***

   And while we are at it…
5. Refrain from installing too many (or the latest trending) plugins. If you feel that a certain plugin would be useful, search for alternatives on vim.org and compare before you jump on the bandwagon.
6. Similarly, avoid "distributions" like the plague. They change too many things and will drag you back on your path to enlightenment.
7. Get to know how to use the `:help`. Answers to most of your questions are there.

Comment: A couple of additional ones to add to romainl's: (1) It sounds like vim was being started from a shortcut or that the starting working dir was c:\windows\system32. Check the "Start In" folder in the properties of the shortcut. For (2) and (3): You can set your $HOME permanently using cmd.exe command: `setx HOME %USERPROFILE%`

Comment: @darcyparker, your comment deserves to become an answer.

Comment: @romainl thank you very much. Your answer is really helpful. as it turns out, yes Vim cannot creat swap file under `C:`. This is strange. So I guess when Vim create some file in some directory, it employs a different mechanism from it if I just right click and select `new` .

Comment: @romainl Also I have tried the vimtutor and yes it is really a nice tutorial for beginners like me. But it is also a very short and limited tutorial and almost covers no lesson about file manipulations besides text-editing skills. Once again, thanks my friend, your answer is deeply appreciated.

Comment: @darcyparker That's brilliant! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MathCs, yes, `vimtutor` is all about learning the basics of text editing in Vim quickly. The lack of "medium level" or "advanced" tutorials is often discussed but there's no definitive answer to that, I'm afraid. I'm a fervent supporter of the "learn as you go" method so it doesn't bother me much. Maybe you should take a look at http://www.reddit.com/r/vim or visit us on #vimrc.

Comment: `:helpgrep` is also very useful but for many questions a google search will be the quickest way to find out how to perform a specific task, mainly because google does a much better job of fuzzy matching search queries than does vim.